# Book tells me to solve separable diffeq with integrating factor, am I missing something?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Maybe this is for purely pedagogical purposes but the book I am using instructs me to solve
$$
ydx+(1-x)dy=0
$$
By finding an appropriate integrating factor and solving. But 
$$
ydx+(1-x)dy=0\Rightarrow (1-x)dy=-ydx\Rightarrow \frac{-dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{1-x}\\
\Rightarrow -\ln(y)=-\ln|1-x|+c \Rightarrow y(x)=A(1-x)
$$
Which gives an explicit solution for $y(x)$.

Comment: Sometimes DFQ's can be solved in more than one way. Your example seems to be one of them. Perhaps this exercise is from a section where the author wants you to practice the method of integration factor. There are a lot of DFQ's that can be done with integration factor but not through separation of variables.

Comment: that makes sense, it just seemed weird. I guess if you can solve for it explicitly this easily, you can always solve for it explicitly after the implicit method.

Comment: When introducing a new method of solving a DE sometimes it is helpful to use a problem which you already know how to solve by a different method so you can check your result.

Comment: Possibly they're just trying to illustrate the fact that if you have any separable equation and write it as $Mdx+Ndy=0$ then there is always an integrating factor. Take the original equation and multiply by $ (y(1-x))^{-1}$; the resulting equation is exact, and if you solve it using the exact-equation technique you find you're doing exactly the same thing as if you solve it as a separable equation.

Comment: Heh: Now show that if you take a _linear_ equation and write it as $Mdx+Ndy=0$ there is an integrating factor, which turns out to be exactly the same as the integrating factor you learned about in the chapter on linear equations. The exact-equation thing includes both those "previous" methods.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you for the exercise, that sounds like it will clarify

Comment: "Integrating factor" is from the horror shop of mathematical misconceptions. Throw away the book, or "they" will put bad memories into your brain.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter differential equations seems to be a real hotspot for sweeping things under the rug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I did it the books way as well, but it didn't quite work out. I thought about posting another question, but thought it would be more useful for future users to have it all in one thread. Here is my attempt at the answer.

$$ydx+(1-x)dy=0$$
Yields an integrating $I(x)$ factor of
$$\frac{1}{1-x}(1-(-1))=\frac{2}{1-x}\Rightarrow \exp(2\int\frac{dx}{1-x})\\
=\exp(-2\ln|1-x|)\Rightarrow I(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
Which yields the exact equation
$$
\frac{y}{(1-x)^2}dx+\frac{1}{1-x}dy=0
$$
And solving for some $G(x,y)=c$
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{1-x}\Rightarrow G(x,y)=\ln|1-x|+h(x)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=\frac{y}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1}{1-x}+h'(x)\\
h'(x)=\frac{y+x-1}{(1-x)^2}\Rightarrow h(x)=y\int\frac{dx}{(1-x)^2}+\int\frac{(x-1)dx}{(1-x)^2}\\
=y\int\frac{dx}{(1-x)^2}-\int\frac{dx}{(1-x)}\Rightarrow h(x)=\frac{y
}{1-x}-\ln|x|+c\\
$$
Yielding the class of solutions:
$$
G(x,y)=c=\ln|1-x|-\ln|x|+\frac{y
}{1-x}\Rightarrow [c-\ln|\frac{x-1}{x}|](x-1)=y(x)
$$

Comment: "As suggested": What you did here is not what _I_ suggested, in case that was what you were referring to. I suggested an integrating factor $\frac1{y(1-x)}$. I said the other day that if you write a separable equation in the form $Mdx+Ndy=0$ then there is an integrating factor - the procedure for finding an integrating factor you learned in the exact-equation section may not work, I was referring to an "obvious" integrating factor. The point being that multiplying by the "obvious" integrating factor is the same as separating variables, showing that technique is contained in this one.